# Running a python script which uses paramiko to ssh into other server and perform db refresh from jenkins

Tags: python, linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a python script that does some Database operations from an ec2 server by SSHing into another server using paramiko. The script runs fine when I run it directly from the server as ec2-user but when I run the same from Jenkins I get a permission error on /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa file.

used `python3.8 /home/ec2-user/db_refresh.py` command to run the script from Jenkins

After some reading and with the help of `whomai` command, I found that's expected since Jenkins runs the scripts as Jenkins user and no one part from the owner has permissions to read private keys in ~/.ssh/ folder.

I could change the permission so that everyone can read ec2-user's private key but I think that would be a terrible idea(As far as I've read) and I think ssh wouldn't even work if anyone apart from the owner has read permission to that private key(I remember reading it somewhere but not sure)

```
sshcon = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshcon.connect(MYSQL_HOST, username=SSH_USERNAME, key_filename='/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

That is how SSH into my database server using paramiko.

Can I run my scripts from jenkins as ec2-user or is there some other way that I can overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turned to be quite simple(stupid me)

I just created a key pair for Jenkins user and used it for doing my operations.

One thing to note is since jenkins is service account normal `su jenkins` won't work. I had to do this `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`.